# How to avoid Can't perform a React state update error when i use ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

I got an error :

```js
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

And I have been trying to find what makes that error and I found the thing that makes an error.

so I tried to search how to avoid this error in this case. but I couldn't find it.

so The problem is when I upload the csv file and then the file contains `info` state.
so I show this file information on my website.
And when the file is uploaded then the component is changing
So I used it with the ternary operator. So I tried to remove the ternary operator then the error had disappeared I assumed that it made the error .

So I'm trying to fix it but I can't figure it out

here is my code :

```js
const CsvShowData = ({ info, setInfo }) => {
  return (
    //
    <>
      {info.length !== 0 ? (
        <DataTable>
          {info.slice(0, 1).map(inf => (
            <MainRow key={inf}>
              {inf.map((d, index) => (
                <Row key={index}>
                  <div className="titleRow">
                    <h3>{d}</h3>
                  </div>
                </Row>
              ))}
            </MainRow>
          ))}

          {info.slice(1, 10).map((a, key) => (
            <MainRow key={key}>
              {a.map((b, idx) => (
                <Row key={idx}>
                  <div className="sideRow">
                    <p>{b}</p>
                  </div>
                </Row>
              ))}
            </MainRow>
          ))}
        </DataTable>
      ) : (
        <CsvTable>
          <CsvFileReader info={info} setInfo={setInfo} />
        </CsvTable>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Thank you in advance!

### CsvFileReader Component

```js
const CsvFileReader = ({ setInfo }) => {
  const handleOnDrop = data => {
    const infos = data.map(item => item.data);
    setTimeout(() => setInfo([...infos]), 1000); // save timeout ref
  };
  const handleOnError = (err, file, inputElem, reason) => {
    console.log(err);
  };

  const handleOnRemoveFile = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MainReader>
        <CSVReader
          onDrop={handleOnDrop}
          onError={handleOnError}
          config={
            (({ fastMode: true }, { chunk: "LocalChunkSize" }),
            { header: false })
          }
          addRemoveButton
          onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
        >
```

Comment: Please show full your component with change state ...

Comment: I did ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a ref to save `setTimeout` and remove `setInfo` when component is unmounted.

```
const ref = useRef();

const handleOnDrop = (data) => {
  const infos = data.map((item) => item.data);
  ref.current = setTimeout(() => setInfo([...infos]), 1000); // save timeout ref
};

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      clearTimeout(ref.current);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much !  i did the same as u did but i still got the error .

Comment: Maybe you have other `setTimeout`

Comment: when I remove ternary operator in `CsvShowData` i don't get the error.